# client certs appear to be accessible even after removing them from APIM

Tags: azure-api-management

I've been playing around with Azure's API Management service and came across some unexpected behavior. Specifically, I've been reading about using certs for client authentication as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients). I'm interested in checking the incoming thumbprint against the certs already uploaded to API management. The Azure example gives you the following example for achieving this:

```
<choose>
<when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || !context.Deployment.Certificates.Any(c => c.Value.Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint))" >
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
    </return-response>
</when>
```

Using Postman and some mocked responses on the API side this works as expected. Incoming messages that have the cert work and others return a 403. What is odd is I then removed the cert from the Client Certificates page on the Azure API Management portal and my request from Postman still makes it through. I was expecting them to be rejected since the cert is gone.

Removing the cert from Azure was successful, at least according to the notifications presented to me in the portal. I also tried it again after an hour or so thinking that it might need sometime to process.

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, and will be fixed shortly. For now you'll have to change, for example, policy to force APIM to throw away certificate from runtime.